# What is the relation between fix points of random uniform permuation, and probability of independent events occuring.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be independent events that occur with probability $1/n$ each. Let

$p_{n,k}=P($exactly $k$ events occur).

One can show with stirlings formula that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n,k}=\frac{1}{ek!} $

Now consider the uniform distribution on $S_n$ the symmetric group of $n$ letters. Let

$q_{n,k}=P(\lbrace \sigma\in S_n |\sigma$ has exactly $k$ fixed points$\rbrace)$.

Again one show that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}q_{n,k}=\frac{1}{ek!} $

I am looking for an intuitive argument as to why this holds? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a given point is a fixed point is $1/n$ (trivially). Since different points are "not too dependent", we expect that the number of fixed points behave like $\mathrm{Bin}(n,1/n)$ (a binomial random variable), and it is known that as $n\to\infty$, $\mathrm{Bin}(n,1/n) \to \mathrm{Po}(1)$, a Poisson random variable with the same expectation. This is known as the *Poisson paradigm* and is important in random graph theory.

Suppose that for each $n$ we are given a set of $n$ events. Using Bonferroni's inequalities you can show that if for some $\lambda$ and each $k$ the probability that $k$ specific events happen tends to $(\lambda/n)^k$ (not necessarily uniformly!), then for each $k$ the probability that in total exactly $k$ events happen tends to $e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k/k!$, and so the number of events is asymptotically distributed as $\mathrm{Po}(\lambda)$.

Comment: That makes sense. How does that relate to the fixed points permutations of $S_n$?

Comment: The probability that $k$ specific points are fixed points is $1/n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) \sim 1/n^k$, so Bonferroni's inequalities show that the distribution of number of points tends to a Poisson random variable with expectation $1$.